# cannot install version 0.3 artisaninweb

Tags: soap-client, laravel-5.4

Using laravel 5.4 I'm trying to use soapwrapper ([artisaninweb](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)) version 0.3, but always get an error:

> Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper' not found

When installing version 0.2 everything works correctly.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your **SoapController**:

```
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\SoapWrapper;
```

Or check in your config/app.php the aliases, it should be:

```
    'aliases' => [
...
        'SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper::class,
...
    ],
```

Any time you change your app.php, you should run: composer dump-autoload.
I guess this last one was your use, let me know.